# Cannot set documentclass size parameter

Tags: errors, fontsize, report

I am using LaTeX to write a report, my header is :

```
    \documentclass[12pt]{extreport}
%packages
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[top=2cm,bottom=2.5cm,left=4cm,right=3cm,headsep=10pt,a4paper]{geometry} % Page margins
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[pangram]{blindtext}%used to fill paragraphs
\usepackage{extsizes}

%declarations

\author{Authors}
\title{Title}
\date{Date}


\newcommand{\chap}[1]{\chapter*{#1}\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}}%used to not displayer chapter 1 2 etc
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection\arabic{subsection}.}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}.}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5} 

\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm}


\begin{document}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\rfoot{test}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\lfoot{test}
\rhead{test}
\lhead{test}
\renewcommand{\headheight}{13pt}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{2pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{2pt}
\renewcommand{\headsep}{25pt}    

\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\setcounter{section}{0}
\chap{Introduction}
    Something
    \newpage
        \section{test}
            \Blindtext[3][7]


\end{document}
```

I get the following error with extreport and also report:

```
! You can't use `the character 1' after \the.
```

It seems to appear when I added the header and footer.

How to fix this ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I get no error from this.

Comment: I edited the code, it should not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst `\headrulewidth` and `\footrulewidth` are to be set using `\renewcommand` (they are commands of `fancyhdr`), `\headheight` and `\headsep` are internal LaTeX parameters and should be set with

```
\setlength
```

So using

```
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{2pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{2pt}
\setlength{\headheight}{13pt}
\setlength{\headsep}{25pt}
```

will do.

However, setting these parameters is better done with `geometry`, as you're using it:

```
\usepackage[
  a4paper,
  top=2cm,
  bottom=2.5cm,
  left=4cm,
  right=3cm,
  headsep=25pt,
  headheight=14.5pt
]{geometry} % Page margins
```

Note that `fancyhdr` tells you that the head height should be at least 14.5pt, so I used the recommended value in the code above.

Here's a refurbished version of your code:

- `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` is almost mandatory when French is used
- it's better to say `\usepackage{mathptmx}` instead of `\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm}`
- the settings for `fancyhdr` should be in the preamble
- you don't need `\usepackage{extsizes}` as you already load `extreport`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{extreport}

%packages
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[
  a4paper,
  top=2cm,
  bottom=2.5cm,
  left=4cm,
  right=3cm,
  headsep=25pt,
  headheight=14.5pt
]{geometry} % Page margins
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[pangram]{blindtext}%used to fill paragraphs

\newcommand{\chap}[1]{%
  \chapter*{#1}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
}%used to not displayer chapter 1 2 etc
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection\arabic{subsection}.}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}.}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5} 

\pagestyle{fancy}
\rfoot{test}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\lfoot{test}
\rhead{test}
\lhead{test}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{2pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{2pt}

%declarations
\author{Authors}
\title{Title}
\date{Date}



\begin{document}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\chap{Introduction}

Something
\newpage

\section{test}

\Blindtext[3][7]

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Babajaga I've added other recommendations about the code